# Using data and headers in Python POST request

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

to be upfront this is for a uni assignment.

I have a webpage that I need to submit a POST request to with Python. The page has a textbox where I need to manually craft and input a HTTP request. If the crafted HTTP request is the correct format the page in the request will be returned.

I can do this manually so know the format of the HTTP request I am entering. It will be something in the form:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: kb.website.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I have then proxied this POST request through Burp to get the headers and data format being sent in order to then recreate this within Python. From this I've created the following

```
url = "https://haas.website.com/"
payload = {'request': 'GET+%2F+HTTP%2F1.1%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A+Mozilla%2F4.0+%28compatible%3B+MSIE5.01%3B+Windows+NT%29%0D%0AHost%3A+kb.website.com%0D%0AAccept-Language%3A+en-us%0D%0AAccept-Encoding%3A+gzip%2C+deflate%0D%0AConnection%3A+Keep-Alive'}
headers = {'Host': 'haas.website.com', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length': '232', 'Origin': 'https://haas.website.com', 'Connection': 'close', 'Referer': 'https://haas.website.com/', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, cert=('key-name.pem', 'key-name.key'))
```

however I'm getting a 400 reply when the original request sent by the browser received a 200 and returned the request page.

The certs work fine as these are being used elsewhere in other requests. I am pretty sure it is something to do with the data and/or header options in requests.posts.

If anyone can assist that would be great. I've included a screen cap of the intercept request in Burp for reference.

Intercepted POST:

[image: Intercepted POST]

Answer (score 0):

I can see what the issue is.

I have taken the string in the request and entered as-is into the python script. This string was encoded already but is being encoded again when it is sent by the script.

By instead doing the following

```
request = """GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: kb.website.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive"""

payload = {'request':  request}

response = requests.post(url1, data=payload, headers=headers1, cert=('key-name.pem', 'key-name.key'))
```

The original string is only encoded once and the POST request is successful.